# How to make global variable reactive in Svelte?

Tags: javascript, variables, svelte, reactive

The following code does not run when I update the `window.test` variable, I do not have any log displaying on my console. I thought that `test()` would be run. Can't we make global variable reactive using svelte ?

```js
  $: window.test && test();

  function test() {
    console.log('success');
  }
```

Comment: You can use  [`store`s](https://svelte.dev/docs#run-time-svelte-store) for that.

Comment: I did not want to use a store for that, I had a simple need

Answer (score 3):

No, we can't make global (or imported) variables reactive.
Svelte's reactivity for assignments is restricted to local variables inside *.svelte files.

The recommended method to enable reactivity in other places is by creating stores, either by using [svelte/store](https://svelte.dev/docs#run-time-svelte-store) directly or by using objects that fulfill the [Store contract](https://svelte.dev/docs#component-format-script-4-prefix-stores-with-$-to-access-their-values-store-contract).